# Is using magic methods in high level Python code is allowed by PEP8?

Tags: python, pep8

Is using magic methods in high level Python code is allowed by PEP8 ? For example, does PEP8 allows for:

```
ab = {'a', 'b'}
ab.__len__()
```

?

I often write code in editors when it's much easier to write left to right without going back to the beginning of a line.

Comment: Sounds like the real problem is the editor.  Have you considered something modal? In vim/emacs with evil/etc I can `esc I` to start inserting at the (indented) beginning of the current line, which is often where I meant to put `len(`, or `ESC b i` to go to the beginning of the current word and insert there, etc.  I'm sure there are decent solutions in non-modal editors, I just don't use them much.  But I don't think one's editor should dictate code style.

Comment: @2e0byo for me problem is jumping to the beginning of line - it is really inconvenient, chaining operations is mote natural for me

Comment: @Obik You could make a method called `length()` that returns `len(self)` if you want the best of both worlds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `__len__` directly doesn't violate PEP8, however, should be avoided as the inbuilt functions that use the magic methods do additional checks.

Example:

```
class Test:

    def __len__(self):
        return "hi"


print(Test().__len__()) # Prints hi
print(len(Test()))  # Prints "TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"
```

Comment: Another risk: Most special methods are looked up directly on the class, even if I make `t = Test()` then do `t.__len__ = lambda: return 'garbage'`, `len(t)` will call the *class*'s `__len__`, and this is the efficient and correct thing to do. `t.__len__()` would call the nameshadowing function on the instance.

Comment: very good, thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, but i don't recommended do some like this.
These are magic methods, they do not need to be called explicitly.

The best solution: len(obj), next(obj), etc.